# Game kit authentication

Tags: ios, gamekit

In the game kit guide its stated that a game should

> If there is not an authenticated user on the device when your game
>   calls this method, Game Kit displays a user interface that allows the
>   player to sign in with their credentials (or to create a new account
>   if he or she has never used Game Center). **Your game should pause other
>   activities that require user interaction** (such as a real time game
>   loop) before attempting to authenticate the local player. ([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLocalPlayer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKLocalPlayer/authenticateWithCompletionHandler%3a))

Should my game just be there unresponsive until game kit does its thing and call the block? is there any way I can receive a notification when such a view shows and hides so my app just doesn't do nothing until its authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

My game is all UIKit-based, and I do nothing special.

Comment: I use real time game loop, which apple explicitly mentions to pause. also, scroll views don't work if I don't stop the game loop, so the new account view won't work.

Comment: Then you should probably only start your loop in the completion handler.

Comment: what will I do when the app returns from background? it will start the loop twice

Comment: I imagine nothing, because you need to wait for the Game Center authentication.